# QML TextArea won't scroll

Tags: qml, qtquickcontrols2

I added a simple `TextArea` in my application. Unfortunately, I can't scroll through the text even if its `contentHeight` bypasses its `height`.
Here is the code:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: appWindow
    visible: true
    width: 480
    height: 640
    TextArea{
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 100
        wrapMode: TextEdit.Wrap
        Component.onCompleted: {
            console.log("width:", width)
            console.log("contentWidth:", contentWidth)
            console.log("height:", height)
            console.log("contentHeight:", contentHeight)
        }
        onTextChanged: {
            console.log("width:", width)
            console.log("contentWidth:", contentWidth)
            console.log("height:", height)
            console.log("contentHeight:", contentHeight)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TextArea` is not scrollable by default, mainly to make it possible to have multi-line editors as part of a scrollable page without having nested `Flickable`s, which often gives sub-optimal experience. In order to make a standalone `TextArea` scrollable, you can attach it to a `Flickable` as illustrated in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-textarea.html).

Comment: I initially wanted to do this with a Label which gets predefined text from my server. Even when using a Flickable, I can't scroll through the label :/

Comment: Can you please include a code for a `Label` in `Flickable` which I can scroll through in your answer?

Comment: Bind `Flickable::contentHeight` to the label's height.

Comment: Can't believe it was so easy! Thank you so much!